# Custom adapter on gallery getView method running multiple time

Tags: android, gallery, custom-adapter

I have made a gallery in which I am showing the image, I have set the custom adapter on gallery. when I run the application ,it run correctly but the getView method of custom adapter is running mutiple times,as it is calling the number of times;but i have called it only once. Below is my code.

```
gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

the above line setting the custom adapter for gallery.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        tv.setText(names[position]);

        previousButton.setClickable(true);

        nextButton.setClickable(true);

        if (position == 0)
        {
            previousButton.setClickable(false);
        } 
        else if (position == 111)
        {
            nextButton.setClickable(false);
        }


        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                     System.out.println("getview method::  "+ viewCheck++);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();

        if (width >= 720 && height >= 1280) 
        {
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(720, 680));
        } 
        else if (width >= 480 && height >= 800) 
        {
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(480, 440));
        }
        else if (width >= 320 && height >= 480) 
        {
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(320, 250));
        }

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question - what behavior are you seeing, and what behavior are you expecting?

Comment: I am seeing the images on gallery which is correct, but the getView method is running multiple times for a single view.

Comment: `getView()` method of an adapter gets called for each of the row of your list. so here your getView() will be called for the times which returned by `getCount()` method. Please specify what problem you are actually facing.

Comment: put a boolean there and skip the code of getview if you want to execute it only once.

Comment: @user3155906 What is your `mImageIds` ?

Comment: mImageIds is an array

Comment: Where you have added the values into it ? @user3155906

Comment: in the same class,it is declared as global for the same class